# textarea not the same width as input field

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I have a a contact form with two input fiels (name and surname) and a bigger textarea field. But this textarea has not the same width as the other two input fields (see picture). I tried several things but I couln't get it worked. Can someone help me to solve this problem? I am using bootstrap.

Here is my code:

```
    <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="validationCustom01">Vorname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="Vorname" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Bitte geben Sie einen gültigen Vornamen ein.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="validationCustom02">Nachname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Nachname" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Bitte geben Sie einen gültigen Nachnamen ein.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                    placeholder="Email" required>
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Wir werden Ihre E-Mail niemals an Dritte
                    weitergeben.</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Nachricht</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8"
                        placeholder="Nachricht" required></textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Nachricht ein.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
                    Agree to terms and conditions
                </label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    You must agree before submitting.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Senden</button>
    </form>
```

[image: textarea]

Comment: well 6 is greater than 4

Comment: I know. If i change it to ```<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3">```´than it becomes as wide as the email field. But I want that the textarea is as wide as Name and Surname input field

Comment: got it: it needs to be `col-md-8`

Answer (score 2):

Text area is

```
col-md-6 col-sm-6
```

Text boxes are

```
col-md-4 mb-3
```

So textarea is half and textbox is a third.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the classes `col-md-6` and `col-sm-6`. The other Inputs have width 4. Maybe you want to change the classes on the Textarea to `col-md-8` and `col-sm-8`.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom01">Vorname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="Vorname" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Bitte geben Sie einen gültigen Vornamen ein.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-3">
        <label for="validationCustom02">Nachname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Nachname" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          Bitte geben Sie einen gültigen Nachnamen ein.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email" required>
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Wir werden Ihre E-Mail niemals an Dritte
                    weitergeben.</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <!-- change the following line to col-...-8 -->
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Nachricht</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8" placeholder="Nachricht" required></textarea>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Nachricht ein.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
                    Agree to terms and conditions
                </label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
          You must agree before submitting.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Senden</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Snipped only works in fullscreen, because of the other classes you have used.

Comment: it helped but if i shrunk the screen at one point it is smaller than the other two input fields

Comment: Yes, because the inputs only have `col-md-...` which is not applied in small screens.

Comment: I updated the snippet, so its responsive now. Therefore I moved the form in a `container`-div. Hope it helps better now.

Comment: [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/) are the official docs, which explain the bootstrap grid very well. maybe you want to look at it for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This should set width of textarea same as input.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Nachricht</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="8" placeholder="Nachricht" required></textarea>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Nachricht ein.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```